# One to many relationship with a composite key table

Tags: ms-access, one-to-many, composite-primary-key

There may be a better way to do this, but here it is

I am trying to record shipping prices

The elements are

- shipping zone
- shipping weight
- 3 carriers UPS, USPS, FEDEX
- 7 Zones 2 through 8

Table 1
UID
Zone (PK)
Weight (PK)
*so you can't create a duplicate combination"

Table 2
UID
UPS Price
USPS Price
FEDEX Price

How do I add the 3 entries to each combo in in Table 1

Hopefully I explained that well

Not sure how to add a one to many relationship with the composite key table

Or if there is a better way to do this

Comment: I avoid composite keys. A composite index is another matter. Table 2 is not truly normalized. Perhaps Table1 should be: Zone, Weight, Price, Shipper. Your question is too broad, does not have code for analysis, no data sample, and responses would generally be opinion - therefore not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Otherwise, perhaps need a 3rd table: UID, ZoneWeight_FK, Price_FK. Then a Shipments table would save UID from 3rd table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are still working on Table Normalization.  In that case here is an example:

```
-------------------------------------------
|     CarrierID      |    CarrierName     |
-------------------------------------------
|                  1 | UPS                |
-------------------------------------------
|                  2 | USPS               |
-------------------------------------------
|                  3 | FEDEX              |
-------------------------------------------
```

[image]

```
sql:

SELECT Carriers.CarrierName, Zones.ZoneName, ShippingCostFormulas.ShippingCostFormulaName, ShippingCosts.Weight, ShippingPrice([Weight],[ZoneID],[CarrierID]) AS ShippingPrice
FROM Carriers INNER JOIN (Zones INNER JOIN (ShippingCostFormulas INNER JOIN ShippingCosts ON ShippingCostFormulas.ShippingCostFormulaID = ShippingCosts.ShippingCostFormulaID) ON Zones.ZoneID = ShippingCosts.ZoneFK) ON Carriers.CarrierID = ShippingCosts.CarrierFK;

'results:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    CarrierName     |      ZoneName      |        ShippingCostFormulaName        |       Weight       |     ShippingPrice     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UPS                | two                | FixedPrice                            |                0.2 |                 $0.10 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USPS               | three              | FixedPrice                            |                0.3 |                 $0.17 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FEDEX              | not not four       | FixedPrice                            |                0.3 |                 $0.19 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UPS                | two                | ByWeightZoneCarrier                   |                0.2 |                 $0.10 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USPS               | three              | ByWeightZoneCarrier                   |                0.3 |                 $0.17 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FEDEX              | not not four       | ByWeightZoneCarrier                   |                0.3 |                 $0.19 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
'formulas:
Public Function ShippingPrice(weight As Double, zone As Long, carrier As Long) As Currency

If carrier = 1 Then
ShippingPrice = weight * 0.5
End If
If carrier = 2 Then
ShippingPrice = weight * 0.4 + 0.05
End If
If carrier = 3 Then
Dim price As Currency
price = weight * 0.3 + 0.1
If zone = 1 Or zone = 5 Then
price = price + 0.2
End If
ShippingPrice = price
End If
End Function
```

The Tables need to hold our old data and be able to handle new data.
We don't have full control of Carrier, Zones, and ShippingPriceFormulas hence we need type tables to future proof the database for when ScroogeMcDuck Shipping uses it's own zones and doubles the shipping price.  No need for a composite key.  I'm going to declare the zone-weight part of the question as too vague and guess that you should Consider A data entry form and Data Validation.  Replacing a straight calculated field with a public function like ShippingPrice allows leveraging the full power of VBA and a whole lot more for just a little extra complexity.

The example table structure already needs improvement as weight should be in a packages table and ShippingDate will be important and isn't directly modeled.  Instead ShippingDate is hidden behind making new ShippingPrice rules over time.

it looks like you wanted to compare rates between shippers.  Normally you use the more powerful forms and reports to interact with the data, but a query is good enough for an example:  grab and rearrange the data you need to either show or calculate with and then show the results of the calculations as well,

*Ignore the fixedPriceFunction I lost it on the cutting room floor,
edit: put ShippingPrice in a code module

Comment: I'm not getting my email notices when someone answers, I'm working through this now, I'll get back

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation/education.  Next is to predict the discounts based on the data I've been gathering.  Thanks to this I have a pretty good idea how to add it