# How to pull multiplier value from another table on query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, office365-apps

I am trying to create the inventory from a point of time in the past (31 December 2021). I’m using MS Access 365. I have three tables in which I have to add and to subtract inventory for each product (what I have now plus what I have sold minus what I have bought).
Table:Have + Table:Sold - Table:Bought
= inventory in the end of 2021

However… the unit counts for each product are relatively different… i.e. one piece of cement bag is 50 kg and when I sell or count it, it is per piece but when I insert them the supplier always say in tons which is 20 bags per ton…
So far I have created additional table which includes as follow:
Table:unit count
ID pluralcount multiplier singularcount remarks
1 ton(x20).    20.        Piece.        One ton has 20 pieces of 50kg
2 pack(x6).    6.         Piece.        One pack has 6 pieces of item
.
.
.

As you can see…
One product I might sell in piece and buy in pack etc.

Before I pull all tables of products I have or sold or bought I need to convert their unit count into something comparable…
The real issue is that how am I supposed to use query to get the multiplier value from my Table:unit count?
For example,
I pull data from table:sold and product and customer

ProductID productname customerid customername qty unitsold (multiplier)
1 cementbag c1 SomsakNumthai 1 Ton(x20) 20<<<<<this is what I want

As you can see above… I would like to pull 20 from my table:unit count that “match” with “Ton(x20)” in that query that comes from what I sold…

I want to pull because I need to convert all into singular count unit so that I can aggregate each table and then finally adding and subtracting… please help! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Provide sample data as formatted text tables https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support. If tables have relationship, join them, if not, then DLookup() might be useful.

Comment: The current question is too vague too answer but I suggest adding business rules and terms to your database.  The Access SQL comes with functions like sum but what you need is functions like convertTonsofCementtoBags().  To borrow a programming term SQL quickly leads to wrapping hell so I limit my sql to gathering the information stored in my tables and simple calculations.  Here is a recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78053038/one-to-many-relationship-with-a-composite-key-table/78055745#78055745

Comment: It is a good idea to define a standard unit for every product in your  conversion table. this can be piece or liter or kg etc. Then define for each additional unit you want to have for the product the multiplier to get the standard unit. When you save in your tables Bought/Sold/Have beside the quantity also the unit, you can link your tables via the unit field to your conversion table and create queries which contains the quantity in the standard unit. Then you can start calculating your inventory numbers.